# 403 HTTP Error when doing POST to Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I haven't been able to send a push notification using OAuth2 with Firebase Cloud Messaging v1. I keep getting the 403 Permission Denied error. I've throughly searched the net, and the answer I've seen is to enable the Firebase Cloud Messaging API. It is already enabled.

I have been able to send messages with the API key, but once I noticed it's Legacy, I wanted to look towards the newer version.

Thanks.

Comment: what did you push notification from?

Comment: I tried the push notification from Postman. I supplied:

Comment: Content-Type application/json, the OAuth2 token and the actual message body taken straight from the firebase documentation.